# Show that we can find $u,v$ as functions of $x,y,z$ in some neighbourhood of the point $(1,1,1,1,1)$

Tags: derivatives

Assume that a system of equations is given as below:
$xy^2+xyu+yv=3$
$x^3yz+2xv-u^2v^2=2$

Show that we can find $u,v$ as functions of $x,y,z$ in some neighbourhood of the point $(1,1,1,1,1)$.  Then find $u_x,u_y,u_z,v_x,v_y,v_z$ at the given point.

Note: My problem is that i don't understand the concept of finding $u,v$ in a neighbour of a point. I would appreciate if someone describes it for me with some details. I don't know how that point mentioned in the question effects the answer (How should i use it?).

Comment: Is that really $x^3yt$?

Comment: @TonyK Excuse me... it's $z$... Thank you for mentioning that

Comment: I deduce that you are using a German keyboard layout...

Comment: @TonyK do you have any suggestions about the question? :D

Comment: Well, $(1,1,1,1,1)$ certainly satisfies the equations. I think the question, although badly posed, asks you to show that in some neighbourhood of $(1,1,1,1,1)$, $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x,y,$ and $z$. In other words, for any given $x,y,z$ in the neighbourhood, $u$ and $v$ are uniquely determined.

Comment: @TonyK that's exactly what i wanted to say! U got it the right way... So, how can we show that $u,v$ are uniquely determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct application of [the implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) (IFT). Let $F : \Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^2 \simeq \Bbb R^5 \to \Bbb R^2$ be given by $F(x,y,z,u,v) = (xy^2 + xyu + yv - 3, x^3yz + 2xv - u^2v^2 - 2)$. Notice that $F$ satisfies the following conditions:

- $F(1, 1, 1, 1, 1) = (0,0)$
- $F$ is continuously differentiable
- the differential of $F$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ at $(1,1)$ is an *invertible* linear map $: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ because it is given by

  $$\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac {\partial F_1} {\partial u} & \dfrac {\partial F_1} {\partial v} \\
  \dfrac {\partial F_2} {\partial u} & \dfrac {\partial F_1} {\partial v} \end{pmatrix} (1,1) = 
  \begin{pmatrix} xy & y \\ -2uv^2 & 2x - 2u^2v \end{pmatrix} (1,1) = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

  which has determinant $2 \ne 0$.

From these, the IFT guarantees the existence of a neighbourhood $U$ of $(1,1,1) \in \Bbb R^3$ and of a neighbourhood $V$ of $(1,1) \in \Bbb R^2$, and of a differentiable map $f : U \to V$ such that $f(1,1,1) = (1,1)$ with $F(x,y,z, f(x,y,z)) = 0$, i.e. this will give you $(u,v)$ as a function of $(x,y,z)$, i.e. $(u,v) = f(x,y,z)$. Notice that we do not know $f$ explicitly, we just know that it exists.

Plugging now $(u(x,y,z), v(x,y,z))$ back in $F$ (but now we know that they are functions of $(x,y,z)$ - that's the difference!) we get that

$$\left\{ \begin{eqnarray} xy^2 + xy u(x,y,z) + yv(x,y,z) -3 = 0\\
x^3yz + 2xv(x,y,z) -u(x,y,z)^2 v(x,y,z)^2 - 2 = 0 \end{eqnarray} \right.$$

and now this is an equality on the $U$ given above by the IFT. If we differentiate them both, we get

$$\left\{ \begin{eqnarray} \Bbb d F_1 = 0 \\
\Bbb d F_1 = 0 \end{eqnarray} \right.$$

which means

$$\frac {\partial F_1} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial F_1} {\partial y} = \frac {\partial F_1} {\partial z} = \frac {\partial F_2} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial F_2} {\partial y} = \frac {\partial F_2} {\partial z} = 0$$

which means, explicitly,

$$\left\{ \begin{eqnarray} y^2 + yu(x,y,z) + xy \frac {\partial u} {\partial x} (x,y,z) + y \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} (x,y,z) = 0 \\
2xy + xu(x,y,z) + xy \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} (x,y,z) + v(x,y,z) + y \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} (x,y,z) = 0 \\
xy \frac {\partial u} {\partial z} (x,y,z) + y \frac {\partial v} {\partial z} (x,y,z) = 0 \\
3x^2yz + 2v(x,y,z) + 2x \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} (x,y,z) - 2u(x,y,z) \frac {\partial u} {\partial x} (x,y,z) v(x,y,z)^2 - 2 u(x,y,z)^2 v(x,y,z) \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} (x,y,z) = 0 \\
x^3z + 2x \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} (x,y,z) - 2u(x,y,z) \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} (x,y,z) v(x,y,z)^2 - 2 u(x,y,z)^2 v(x,y,z) \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} (x,y,z) = 0 \\
x^3y + 2x \frac {\partial v} {\partial z} (x,y,z) - 2u(x,y,z) \frac {\partial u} {\partial z} (x,y,z) v(x,y,z)^2 - 2 u(x,y,z)^2 v(x,y,z) \frac {\partial v} {\partial z} (x,y,z) = 0 \ . \end{eqnarray} \right.$$

Applying this in $(1,1,1)$ and remembering that $u(1,1,1) = v(1,1,1) = 1$, we get

$$\left\{ \begin{eqnarray} u_x(1,1,1) + v_x(1,1,1) = -2 \\
u_y(1,1,1) + v_y(1,1,1) = -4 \\
u_z(1,1,1) + v_z(1,1,1) = 0 \\
-2u_x(1,1,1) = -5 \\
-2u_y(1,1,1) = -1 \\
-2u_z(1,1,1) = -1 \ .\end{eqnarray} \right.$$

The 4th, 5th and 6th equations give you $u_x,u_y,u_z$, whence using the 1st, 2nd and 3rd equations you will also get $v_x,v_y,v_z$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the time you spent on these details! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this: [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)

In a nutshell, compute the "partial" Jacobian with respect to $u$ and $v$ of the vector function:

$$
f_1(x,y,z,u,v) = xy^2 + xyu + yv
$$
$$
f_2(x,y,z,u,v) = x^3yz + 2xv -u^2v^2
$$

The partial Jacobian would be:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        f_{1u} & f_{1v}  \\
        f_{2u} & f_{2v}\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

where $f_{ij}$ is the derivative of the i-eth function defined above with respect to the j-eth variable. If the Jacobian is invertible when you evaluate it in $(1,1,1,1,1)$ and given that your function is well behaved, you have a sufficient condition for $u$ and $v$ to be functions of the other variables around that point.